# Equivalence of $L^p$ harmonic functions on the ball and a representation by harmonic homogeneous polynomials

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-functions

In Harmonic function theory, there is a theorem which says that if $u$ is an harmonic function on $B\left(a,r\right)$, then there exist homogeneous harmonic polynomials $p_{m}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $$u\left(x\right)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}p_{m}\left(x-a\right)$$ for all $x\in B\left(a,r\right)$, and the series converges absolutely and uniformly on compact subsets of $B\left(a,r\right)$. Is there any paper about conditions to these homogeneous polynomials that are equivalent to $u\in L^{p}\left(B\left(a,r\right)\right)$, where $1\leq p<\infty$? Here $L^{p}$ denotes a Lebesgue space.